# Using conditional to generate new column in pandas dataframe in my code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The result of code is

```
                  iccid      ipAddress  ...              dateSessionEnded 
0  89610185001538644952  10.129.22.157  ...  2020-11-27 12:37:27.270+0000   
1  89610185001538532829   10.129.60.14  ...                          None  
2  89610185002408618430  10.137.53.218  ...                          None   
3  89610185002413572052  10.128.88.115  ...  2020-11-29 03:46:07.910+0000   
4  89610185002407603007  10.136.93.119  ...  2020-11-26 00:01:37.018+0000
```

I am trying to make a conditional statement to add another column with status that if datasession ended is None than the sim is 'InSession' if it has a datevalue then 'Not In Session'. So far no luck can anyone help.

Kind Regards,

Comment: this is my code from which I am getting the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways for doing such task. For instance, the classic one:

```py
df.loc[~df.dateSessionEnded.isnull(), 'newcol'] = 'Not In Session'
df.loc[df.dateSessionEnded.isnull(), 'newcol'] = 'In Session'
```

or using `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['newcol'] = np.where(df.dateSessionEnded.isnull(), 'In Session', 'Not In Session')
```

or using `map` (it would also work with `replace`):

```
df['newcol'] = (df.dateSessionEnded.isnull()).map({True: 'In Session', False:'Not In Session'})
```

or using `where` with `replace`:

```
df['newcol'] = df.dateSessionEnded.where(lambda x: x.isnull(), 'Not In Session').replace({None:'In Session'})
```

and so on...

---

Output:

```
                  iccid      ipAddress            dateSessionStarted                dateSessionEnded          newcol  
0  89610185001538644952  10.129.22.157  2020-11-26 05:49:56.270+0000    2020-11-27 12:37:27.270+0000  Not In Session  
1  89610185001538532829   10.129.60.14  2020-12-04 03:50:47.105+0000                            None      In Session  
2  89610185002408618430  10.137.53.218  2020-12-03 20:32:08.436+0000                            None      In Session
```

---

**Data**:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'iccid': '89610185001538644952', 'ipAddress': '10.129.22.157', 'dateSessionStarted': '2020-11-26 05:49:56.270+0000', 'dateSessionEnded': '2020-11-27 12:37:27.270+0000'},
    {'iccid': '89610185001538532829', 'ipAddress': '10.129.60.14', 'dateSessionStarted': '2020-12-04 03:50:47.105+0000', 'dateSessionEnded': None},
    {'iccid': '89610185002408618430', 'ipAddress': '10.137.53.218', 'dateSessionStarted': '2020-12-03 20:32:08.436+0000', 'dateSessionEnded': None}
])
```

Comment: Still its not working it shows all as in Session

Comment: Is None a string or `None` python type?

Comment: it is a string.

Comment: the one with date should be out of session and one with none should be in Session

Comment: the confusing part is date

Comment: Then we should invert the bool operators, but you're getting 'InSession' for all??

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hope it works (it worked for the example data you provided). If not, maybe 'None' is not a string (it can be the python `None` type), or it's a string with spaces...

Comment: {'iccid': '89610185001538644952', 'ipAddress': '10.129.22.157', 'dateSessionStarted': '2020-11-26 05:49:56.270+0000', 'dateSessionEnded': '2020-11-27 12:37:27.270+0000'}
{'iccid': '89610185001538532829', 'ipAddress': '10.129.60.14', 'dateSessionStarted': '2020-12-04 03:50:47.105+0000', 'dateSessionEnded': None}
{'iccid': '89610185002408618430', 'ipAddress': '10.137.53.218', 'dateSessionStarted': '2020-12-03 20:32:08.436+0000', 'dateSessionEnded': None}

Comment: the response I get as a result of api call which I convert to dataframe

Comment: and trying to apply the logic which I discussed up

Comment: The `None` from your data is not a string, instead, it's a [`NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/constants.html). That's why so important to provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the questions. I've updated the answer, now using the sample data you provided here in the comments, and working with `Nonetype` rather than "None" (string).

Comment: thanks mate working now really appreciate your help

Comment: Glad to know that. Best!